# How to Set width for dropdown in magento2 system configuration?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, system-configuration

I have created a custom configuration same like `Magento\Braintree\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Countrycreditcard.php`
with some fields like

```
$this->addColumn(
            'field',
            ['label' => __('Field'), 'renderer' => $this->_getAttributesRenderer(),'style' => 'width: 1000px']
        );
```

Even if i set width in style its not working.

Please let me know how to set width.

Comment: @Marius Did you get the chance to look on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
Magento\Braintree\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Cctypes.php` `_toHtml
```

has

```
$this->setExtraParams('multiple="multiple"');
```

So with same function try to set width

```
setExtraParams('style="width:1000px;"');
```

`setExtraParams` **function** accepts any styling or other attributes we can set for select field

Answer (score 0):

I was using this
`Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory` class to generate element and I've added below code and it worked for me.

```
$element = $this->_elementFactory->create('select');
$regions = $this->regionOptions->toOptionArray();
        $element->setForm(
            $this->getForm()
        )->setName(
            $this->_getCellInputElementName($columnName)
        )->setHtmlId(
            $this->_getCellInputElementId('<%- _id %>', $columnName)
        )->setValues(
            $regions
        )->setStyle('width:200px;');
```